# Return Key from PHP multidimensional array search

Tags: php

I have an array that has Regions and States.  Each Region has multiple States.  I want to search the array for a State and have it tell me which Region it is in. The state I'm searching for will ultimately be passed to this function via a form post.

I've tried several things I found on here such as in_array and a custom function but cant seem to get it working.   I'm on PHP 5.3.27 and cant upgrade to 5.5+ so I have to rely on features available to the earlier version.

Here is my array:

```
$regions = array("SE" => array("NC","SC","GA","KY","AL","LA","MS","FL","TN"), "MW" => array("IN","IL","OH","WI","MI"), "SW" => array("MO","OK","KS","AR","TX"), "W" => array("CA","NV"));
```

Comment: How does your current code looks like?

Comment: Just use `array_contains()` in a foreach loop iterating over the regions. Break when you get a hit.

Comment: I dont really have any code other than the array at this point. Every piece code I've tried hasnt actually worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
<?php
$state = $_POST["whatever"];

$regions = array("SE" => array("NC","SC","GA","KY","AL","LA","MS","FL","TN"), "MW" => array("IN","IL","OH","WI","MI"), "SW" => array("MO","OK","KS","AR","TX"), "W" => array("CA","NV"));
foreach ($regions as $key => $region){
    if (in_array($state, $regions[$key])){
        echo $key;
        break;
    }
} 
?>
```

Comment: That works perfectly.  Thanks for that, I am not particularly good with arrays etc so wasnt sure how to get the info I want out of it.

Comment: @JasonM No problem. You should call `break;` after `echo`, so the loop stops.